# Disable search form in nav from collapsing

Tags: search, navigation

Is there a way I can have my search form in nav bar not collapsed when screen size decreases? I'm using bootstrap on Drupal 7

Comment: How do you render your search form? Is it a block assigned into a region?

Comment: If I understood you, I have a search form block in the navigation section and it's set in line with the  main menu

Comment: I see. Do you have page.tpl.php in your theme folder?

Comment: yes, and it's located at 'sites/all/themes/bootstrap_subtheme/templates/page.tpl.php'

Answer (score 0):

You can change your markup using the page.tpl.php

- Copy the `page.tpl.php` file from `/bootstrap/templates/system` to your theme.
- Edit the `page.tpl.php` that you've copied.
- Move the line 108 - 110 below / above the `navbar-collapse collapse` div.

[image]

- Create a new div.
- Put the code from line 108 - 110 into the new div.
- Save
- The changes should be like the screenshot below.

[image]

- Flush cache

Comment: It worked, but the function disabled the collapse of both the main menu and search form. What I wanted was to disable the search form from collapsing, but the rest i.e main menu should collapse. Is that possible?

Comment: I suspect that you have a multiple blocks assigned in navigation region. You might want to consider to create a new region. Edit your theme .info file. At the regions area starting from line 11, create a new region there eg. regions[navigation_right] = 'Navigation Right'
Save. Move back the $page['navigation'] into its original placement. Render your new region Eg. $page['navigation_right']. Save. Flush cache. Move your search block into 'navigation_right' region.

Comment: Or you can check this link to see the samples on how to create new block region. https://www.drupal.org/node/1088718#comment-4194802

Comment: Thank a lot @Madelyn, adding a new region worked perfectly and it'll be useful with a lot more I've been struggling with.

Comment: My pleasure. Good to hear that it suits to your requirements.